# Changing the font size in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, font-size

Is it possible to use any javascript command to change the current font size in a UIWebView (content editable, of course)? I wrote a popup that list font sizes in picas (from 9 to 64), and would like to set the font size to this setting, not to the traditional HTML font-size setting from 1 to 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[webview stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@“foo()“];`

**EDIT:** So your real question is "What javascript command should I use to change the font size of my HTML?" or something like that...

`document.getElementById` will return an element by its ID.  You can then use the `element.style.fontSize` property to change its font size.

Comment: Of course, I already use this method to control UIWebView with javascript command, for example document.execCommand('Bold'). The question is: which command can I use to set the current font size to "mySize" in picas?

Comment: OK, your question isn't very clearly worded, I answered again.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Unfortunately I'm a full newbie with javascript... and I'm not able to translate your solution in a working code...

Comment: Well, the return item of document.getElementById is an element object (`var foo = document.getElementById('bar')`).  You can then edit foo, and watch your changes get applied:  `foo.style.fontSize = 17`.